# List Index Working On macOS but not Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, macos, indexing

So, I made a script on macOS, and distributed it with some friends.

However, I got many complaint from my friends using Windows that the script wasn't working for them.

Sure enough, I installed Windows on a partition and run my script, and it didn't work.

Everyone got the same error.

```
    data[k+1][16] = 0
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here is the sample of the part of code where it fails

```
df = pd.read_csv("passandpy.csv", usecols=[16], skipinitialspace=True)
col16 = df['Failed Attempts'].tolist()
data = [line for line in csv.reader(open('passandpy.csv'))]
data[k+1][16] = 0
csv.writer(open('passandpy.csv', 'w')).writerows(data)
```

What is supposed to happen is that Column 16 is read from the csv file, and converted to a list. Then, I make another list called data, and write all the lines from the csv into that list. I edit on of the values in that list, and then I save the list back into the csv.

One more thing I should mention is that once this script is run on Windows, it will no longer work on macOS as well.

Once I delete the csv file that was made on Windows and generate one with the script using macOS the script works again.

Comment: It probably happens because windows and macOS have different new line delimiter you can look here for the explanation https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Comment: I suppose line for line (you should not name them the same I think) is the culprit. Windows use CR LF as line breaks where as mac only use LF. So youre array is probably filled diferent, hence the error. Afterwards you write it with different line endings and therefore you cant read it anymore on mac

Comment: @Joker I used .splitlines() when I store the information. This is the issue, right?

Comment: Lot's of cool stuff doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the issue.

On Windows, it was writing extra blank lines to the .csv file. This caused the list index to stop working.

I fixed it with this piece of code.

```
data = []
lines = [line for line in csv.reader(open('passandpy.csv','r'))]
for line in lines:
    if line == []:
        continue
```

It filters the blank lines.